# s(t) for t greater than or equal to 0. For each intervals of time when the particle is moving left and moving right.

Tags: calculus

A particle moves along a horizontal line. Its position function is s(t) for t greater than or equal to 0. For each intervals of time when the particle is moving left and moving right.

One of the problems I need help on looks like:
s(t)=-t^2+15t-54

Do you take the derivative then factor? You'd end up with:
s(t)=-2t+15

I don't know what to do!

Answer (score 0):

To be clear of what a positive s(t) means, we first set right hand side is positive.

Beginning with s(t)=-t^2+15t-54,

you take the derivative to get s'(t)=-2t+15

(s'(t) physically means your velocity)

if t>2/15, then s'(t) is positive, thus the particle is moving to the right,

if 0< t<2/15, then s'(t) is negative, thus the particle is moving to the left.